# Question regarding Ethernet PHY transceiver emission

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, ethernet, emc

I see that this [Ethernet PHY](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/LAN8830-Data-Sheet-00004724A.pdf) transceiver has voltage mode, and line drivers. Since it has on-chip termination resistors, I understand that it has voltage mode line driver.

One general question I now have is that,

1. With regards to the Ethernet cable, (Cat6a), which type of line driver will result in more emission issues? Whether voltage mode line driver or current mode line driver will cause more emissions?
2. Can the edge rates be reduced by changing register values?

Comment: The chip does seem to have voltage mode drivers, but it can't be just determined from the fact that it has built-in termination resistors. Also why would voltage or current mode have better or worse EMI when done properly, it would depend on how the chip implements it, and it may require external components to help with EMI, so either one can be implemented poorly or properly by the chip or whole system. And if the edge rates can be controlled, it would read in the manual, or if not, you would have to ask the manufacturer if rate can be controlled.

Comment: @Justme,  the datasheet says it has on-chip termination resistors. Hence, I believed that it would be a good conclusion that the PHY is a voltage mode device. If that's not the right way to deduce that the chip is a voltage mode device, could you tell m how to deduce? Also, in general, if I follow good EMI and identical layout practices on both, current and voltage mode driver PHYs, which would show good performance? Any logic or idea behind it?

Comment: You already seem to know how to decuce the difference; do you remember your earlier question : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/622636/voltage-mode-ethernet-phy-and-current-mode-ethernet-phy about it? And what difference it makes, you have the chip you must use, and you must use like the datasheet says, and hope it passes compliance testing. But the LAN8830 has a hardware issue so it won't be fully compliant anyway.

Comment: LAN8830 has a hardware issue? I am not aware of it. Could you tell me what it is?

Comment: The chip documentation is freely available from the manufacturer website. Please go read them.